# Specifying java classes in XML with XSD

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

I have a Spring and maven based Java web application.

I have one XML file using as a configuration. I am parsing it through JAXB and its working fine. Here is a sample file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sources>
    <source name="source1">
        <bean class="com.myapp.demo.SourceDemo" />
        <bean class="com.myapp.demo.Source2" />
    </source>
</sources>
```

I have generated XSD for this XML. Here is the XSD file..

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="sources">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="source">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="bean" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:simpleContent>
                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                      <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="class" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:extension>
                  </xs:simpleContent>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This I am importing in XML and it's working fine. When I parse I am getting the class value as String.

Now the class attribute value is String. But I want to make it as a class provider so when I start typing class name with package and press Ctrl+Space, it should give the options to fill the class name, **Just like in Spring applicationcontext.xml**.

How can I do that? This is what I have tried.

```
<xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="class" use="optional">
                        <xs:annotation>
                            <xs:documentation source="java:java.lang.Class">
                            </xs:documentation>
                        </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

But when I start typing and press Ctrl+Space, it is not giving any option.

Answer (score 0):

The IDEs (e.g. STS) have editor extensions for Spring XML files. Unless your XML actually *is* a Spring config file, that trick with the metadata in the schema won't work. Sorry.